# ExcelCom writing formula into cell results in #name?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

In my project i have to fill formulas into cells of an ExcelSheet. To do that I use the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` Library.

The code itself is very easy

```
mySheet.Cells[1, 1] = SomeString;
mySheet.Cells[1, 2].Formula = "=SUMME($E$2:E" + SomeInteger + ")";
```

And that's it already. 
(Since I live in germany, my excel version understands "Summe" as "SUM"

Now when looking at the excel sheet, the result ist #name?.
When clicking into the cell, and so forcing it to update, it calculates perfectly.

> I found a few posts related to this, but the link they provided with
>   the solution does not exist anymore. (And are about 10 years old)

I have tried the following steps:

- calling

  mySheet.Calculate()
  after setting the formula. (Did not work)
- Changing the function. Some other functions (simpler ones) work fine. But not mine...

I would be glad to hear from you - more experienced - guys...

Thank you!

Details:
Excel version: 2016
Windows 10

PS: This is my first question. So if you have some tipps concerning that, I would be glad too!

Comment: Yes of course... Sorry I forgot to mention it.

Comment: As I wrote, when clicking into the cell and then hitting enter, it executes perfectly.

Comment: Try the answer as suggested by @PLED. You can try with `.value` as well.

Comment: In the meantime I don't have access to the project itself anymore but I use other excel libraries now (epplus). They do *not support localized Excel-Formulas*. So maybe the solution would be to use `SUM` instead of `SUMME`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem, but with formula in Spanish.
My solution was 2 parts:

1) Change culture to English before initialize Excel Interop:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
_AppExcell = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
```

2) Write formula in English:

```
mySheet.Cells[1, 2].Formula = "=SUM($E$2:E" + SomeInteger + ")";
```

Comment: Sadly I don't have the project to test that anymore. But I guess that you answer would be correct since other Excel libaries do not support localized formulas either. 
So thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at my dev computer to verify this, however I think if you change the second line to ...

```
mySheet.Cells[1, 2].Value2 = "=SUMME($E$2:E" + SomeInteger + ")";
```

you may get the results you seek.

Comment: I could of course somehow "force my way through" and calculate the sum within c# and assign a value manually but I would like to have the formula since the customer could change values later on and it would be nice to have all values updated in that case...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having to convert your formulas to the English version and having to add CultureInfo, you could simply use "FormulaLocal" instead of "Formula". It works like a charm.

So instead of

```
mySheet.Cells[1, 2].Formula = "=SUMME($E$2:E" + SomeInteger + ")"; //#NAME
```

you would use

```
mySheet.Cells[1, 2].FormulaLocal = "=SUMME($E$2:E" + SomeInteger + ")";
```